# capture a repeating group in regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string A_B_C_D_E_F_G and i want to get all strings A,B.. in a array using some regex. I've tried

```
((.*?)_)+
```

However, this only seems to store last repetition. Is there a way to get all of them in a single regex and if not what should I use ?

Also, i'm doing it in C++ using

Comment: Use `_+` and collect non-matching chunks, or vice versa, use `[^_]+` and collect matching chunks.

Comment: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xZBk63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you are using `std::regex_match`

you can use `std::regex_search` or `std::regex_iterator` to do what you want (with regex `([^_]+)`)

Comment: BTW, your `((.*?)_)+` will not match `A_B_C_D_E_F_G`

Comment: Is there a way to do it using regex_match ? I want to check first if the string is the one i need(i.e string_string_string_...) and capture all the substrings using only one regex.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев no,there is no way, and I don't see where `std::regex_search` with `([^_]+)` not fit your need

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев BTW, if your `string` means digit and words, you can use `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?)*` in `regex_match` to check

Comment: thank you, i didn't want to use regex_search due to performance  issues with that approach. Apparently, i don't have a choice.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев I am not sure there will be much difference between `regex_match` and `regex_search`.